Adding a virtual column to SQLTableModel
I use a class that inherits QSQLTableModel associated with a local database.
each role match a column of the database which contains only one table "games".
I display my data in qml, as a list or grid view, and everything works fine.
Now I want to add an extra role to the data, like if I added a new column to the database.
But it does not work.
// Inside the constructor, I add an extra role, and insert a new column at the end.

auto rec = record();
for(int i = 0; i < rec.count(); i++) {
    m_roles.insert(Qt::UserRole + i + 1, rec.fieldName(i).toUtf8()); // role names are column names
}
m_roles.insert(Qt::UserRole + rec.count() + 1, "subgame"); // extra role "subgame"

select();   

insertColumn(columnCount()); // new column
buildCodeMap(); // fill new column

I redefined columnCount and index function to take in account this extra column
int SqlTableModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return QSqlTableModel::columnCount(parent) + 1;
}

QModelIndex SqlTableModel::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if (!hasIndex(row, column, parent) && (column == columnCount() - 1)) {
        return createIndex(row, column);
    }

    return QSqlTableModel::index(row, column, parent);
}

Here is data() and setData() function, nothing special except column index is recalculated from role value.
QVariant SqlTableModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (index.isValid()) {
        if (role >= Qt::UserRole) {
            int columnIdx = role - Qt::UserRole - 1;
            QModelIndex modelIndex = this->index(index.row(), columnIdx);
            return QSqlTableModel::data(modelIndex, Qt::DisplayRole);
        }
    }

    return QSqlTableModel::data(index, role);
}

bool SqlTableModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
{
    if (index.isValid()) {
        if (role >= Qt::UserRole) {
            int columnIdx = role - Qt::UserRole - 1;
            QModelIndex modelIndex = this->index(index.row(), columnIdx);
            return QSqlTableModel::setData(modelIndex, value, Qt::EditRole);
        }
    }

    return QSqlTableModel::setData(index, value, role);
}

And here is the function where I add value to the extra column for each data
void SqlTableModel::buildCodeMap()
{
QHash<QString, QStringList> hash;

qDebug() << rowCount();
for (int row = 0; row < rowCount(); ++row) {
    auto tag   = data(index(row, 0), Qt::UserRole + 1).toString(); // tag
    auto code = data(index(row, 0), Qt::UserRole + 6).toString(); // code

    // qDebug() << tag << code;
    QRegularExpression regex("(.+?)(?:/|$)");
    QRegularExpressionMatch match = regex.match(code);

    if (match.hasMatch()) {
        QString numero = match.captured(1);
        hash[numero] << tag;
        if(hash[numero].count() > 1) {
            setData(index(row, 0), true, Qt::UserRole + 9);
        } else {
            setData(index(row, 0), false, Qt::UserRole + 9);
        }
    }

    qDebug() << data(index(row, 0), Qt::UserRole + 9).toBool(); // subgame
}
}

Problem is the data() function always returns false even if I setData with true...
also in qml the model.subgame is "undefined", while every other data are displayed correctly.
Do you have any idea?
Thanks
Here is roleNames()
QHash<int, QByteArray> SqlTableModel::roleNames() const 
{ 
   return m_roles;
}


What is the result of insertColumn()? It probably is false, but if it's true, you cannot then override the behavior of columnCount() without that assumption. It is also wrong to do it in a QSqlTableModel, since the column count is always based on the table. I'd start by removing it: if it's true, then columnCount() becomes unreliable; if it's false, then it's unnecessary anyway. It's unclear how you're actually using m_roles: are you actually returning its data in roleNames()?

I added the rolesNames to the post. Yes insertColumn() returns false. So I can't use it in a QSqlTableModel ? What about using a QIdentityProxyModel and add the new role here ?

The fact is that insertColumn() makes sense when the model has already been set on a view (or an object that accesses its structure) and/or whenever the model implementation requires calling it. In your case there's no point: the virtual column has no direct effect on the SQL implementation (since you implement it on your own) and you're setting it before the model is being used by anything else. It's like when implementing a custom QAbstractTableModel and the model shape is already known at initialization: insertColumn() and related functions will be used only when a new column will »

» actually be inserted after initialization. In your case there's no need, and it's also wrong because it would attempt to add an actual sql field (which doesn't exist and that you don't need). Besides, I'm not fluent in C++, so I may be wrong, but if I'm not mistaken you're calling it using your override of columnCount(), which already returns an increased column number. Interestingly enough, insertColumn() returns false in your case because QSqlQueryModel prevents insertion when the column index is greater than the record count, which you've already exceeded by returning the sql »

» column count + 1: assuming the sql table has 5 columns, your columnCount() returns 6, so you're calling insertColumn(6), which is not possible as there are currently only 5 records. That said, it's not clear what editStrategy you're using, but if you're not explicitly setting it, the default is OnRowChange, and the setData() docs clearly say that changes are not submitted automatically, meaning that in buildCodeMap() you should call submit() for each row after calling setData().

Thanks a lot for your time. Submit is not relevant since I use onFieldChange as edit strategy. actually you are right about columnCount because I'm getting something right now. No need to add +1. And I can add the new column even if the model is not connected yet to the view apparently.
